# Using pthread_mutex_t lock passed to thread

Tags: c, multithreading

I'm learning about concurrency in C. I understand there are a few ways to initialize a pthread_mutex_t.

This simple program runs fine:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

pthread_mutex_t lock = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

void* worker(void* arg) {

    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock); 
    printf("worker says hi\n");
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);

    return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    pthread_t p;
    pthread_create(&p, NULL, worker, NULL);

    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
    printf("master says hi\n");
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);

    pthread_join(p, NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

However, if I don't want the lock to be defined globally, I would think I can define it in my main thread and pass it to the other thread as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void* worker(void* arg) {
    pthread_mutex_t lock = * (pthread_mutex_t *) arg;

    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
    printf("worker says hi\n");
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);

    return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    pthread_mutex_t lock = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

    pthread_t p;
    pthread_create(&p, NULL, worker, &lock);

    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
    printf("master says hi\n");
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);

    pthread_join(p, NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

However, this does *not* work. Rather, it only prints  `master says hi` and hangs.

I thought this might be deadlock, so I inserted some sleep time into the master as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void* worker(void* arg) {
    pthread_mutex_t lock = * (pthread_mutex_t *) arg;

    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
    printf("worker says hi\n");
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);

    return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    pthread_mutex_t lock = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

    pthread_t p;
    pthread_create(&p, NULL, worker, &lock);

    sleep(1);

    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
    printf("master says hi\n");
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);

    pthread_join(p, NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

As expected, this printed out `worker says hi` followed by `master says hi` one second later.

However, if I move the sleep into the worker, below as follows, it hangs again:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void* worker(void* arg) {
    pthread_mutex_t lock = * (pthread_mutex_t *) arg;

    sleep(1);

    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
    printf("worker says hi\n");
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);

    return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    pthread_mutex_t lock = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

    pthread_t p;
    pthread_create(&p, NULL, worker, &lock);

    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
    printf("master says hi\n");
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);

    pthread_join(p, NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

If I put the sleep function *above* the line `pthread_mutex_t lock = * (pthread_mutex_t *) arg;` then it *doesn't* hang. I'm not sure how to explain this behavior.

Comment: I think you made a copy of the `mutex`.

Comment: *However, this does not work. Rather, it only prints master says hi and hangs.*  I did copy&paste (the first code where you pass the lock as a thread argument) and I worked without a problem. But instead of doing `pthread_mutex_t lock = * (pthread_mutex_t *) arg;` (which creates a copy of the lock), I'd do `pthread_mutex_t *lock =  arg;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `worker` function is making a copy of the mutex, when it should just use the existing mutex. The fix is to declare the `lock` variable as a pointer to the mutex:

```
void* worker(void* arg) {

    pthread_mutex_t *lock = arg;

    pthread_mutex_lock(lock);
    printf("worker says hi\n");
    pthread_mutex_unlock(lock);

    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: Ahhh so it's the dereferencing of the pointer to a struct that makes a _copy_ of that struct?!

Comment: @allstar Yup, that's the issue. The mutex is just a struct, and the code was making a copy.

Answer (score 3):

I did copy&paste all your examples and not a single one hanged or showed your behaviour.

I'm not quite sure, but I assume the problem lies in the thread function here:

```
pthread_mutex_t lock = * (pthread_mutex_t *) arg;
```

This creates a bitwise copy of the original mutex and depending on the contents
of the structure, this could lead to the problems you are seeing. Hence different implementations/versions of glibc+pthreads might yield different results.

I always pass my locks as a parameter to the thread, and I don't have the
problem, however I don't create copies of my locks, so I'd try this instead:

```
void* worker(void* arg) {
    pthread_mutex_t *lock = arg;

    pthread_mutex_lock(lock);
    printf("worker says hi\n");
    pthread_mutex_unlock(lock);

    return NULL;
}
```

this should solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you for your answer as well, I think sorted by time the other one came in just before yours :P